# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, internal-server-error

I'm seriously going crazy because in the last 5 hours I obtain the same error when I start my app.

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)

The server is ok, there aren't problems there. I tried to change https in http from the applicationUrl string. Doesn't work.

Comment: did you change anything? deleted something? added something?

Comment: I've add a new table and after that this error. I restored in the previous state, but nothing.

Comment: did you try restarting the app?

Comment: Yep. Nothing change.

Comment: well, enable logging and check the logs, since the error like this is pretty useless

Comment: How can I enable logging? Only I can see is that there is an HTTP server Error if I try to read or insert or update or remove an item in any table of my database.

Comment: THe MobileServiceInvalidOperationException is a composite error and contains the HTTP request and response.  You can also turn on diagnostic logging in your backend and then use Log Stream to see the output.  You can also look at the FREB logs to see a particular transaction and see what the server saw.

Comment: i'm still here. If I try to make a simple insert, it doesn't work without any exception. Simply it not happens. Otherwise I have exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error) if I made a query in any table.

Answer (score 1):

The `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` is a wrapper exception - there is an inner exception that explains what the issue is.  Given the Internal Server Error message, I'm guessing that the server is returning `500 Internal Server Error`.  This is a generic server error that basically means "The server crashed for some reason", which isn't helpful.

To diagnose, go to your Azure website and select Diagnostic logging in the menu.  Turn on Application Logging and set the verbosity to Verbose.  Then go to Log Stream (which is directly below the Diagnostic logging settings in the menu) to start looking at a live view of the logs.  You will see the exception once you retry the request.

As an alternative, you can use remote debugging, which I love.  Once you know what routine the exception is being caused in, you can set a breakpoint in that routine within Visual Studio, then go to the Cloud Explorer, log into Azure, and start a remote debugging session on the backend.  Again, send your request and you can inspect the internal state of the method during the request.

If you need to see the request itself, you can look at the FREB logs, which are XML files that are stored for every single failed request.  You need to turn on failed request logging for this to work, which is done in Diagnostic logging.